# Does this minimum exist? Modified Ascoli theorem without countable choice

Tags: real-analysis, axiom-of-choice, supremum-and-infimum, proof-explanation, arzela-ascoli

I am trying to work through a [proof](https://books.google.de/books?id=PjzTBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA192&lpg=PA192&dq=rhinegost%20modified%20ascoli&source=bl&ots=15QCvHEa0m&sig=UPpWbDOS30cOk4ffVYd7oGKq9oY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVhMammLPLAhUFG5oKHfE6DI0Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=rhinegost%20modified%20ascoli&f=false) on a modification of the ascoli theorem that is supposed to hold in ZF (even **without assuming countable choice**).

My problem is within the part (1) $\Rightarrow$ (2b):

Let $F$ be a set of continous functions from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and let each sequence in $F$ have a subsequence converging continously to $g$. We want to show each countable subset $G$ of $F$ is equicontinous.

Suppose not, then there is a countable subset $G \subseteq F$ with elements $f_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ which isn't equicontinous.
By definition there exists $x \in \mathbb{r}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$ there is $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$|x - y| < \delta \text{ and } |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| \geq \varepsilon$$

In the next step we define
$$\nu(n) := \min\left\{m \in \mathbb{N} \mid \text{there exists } y \in [x - 2^{-n}, x + 2^{-n}] \text{ with } |f_m(x) - f_m(y)| \geq \varepsilon \right\}$$
Because of the well ordering of the naturals $\nu(n)$ is well defined.

Now set $g_n := f_{\nu(n)}$ and define
$$x_n := \min \left\{ y \in [x - 2^{-n}, x + 2^{-n}] \mid |g_n(x) - g_n(y)| \geq \varepsilon \right\}.$$

Why does this minimum exists? Is it maybe just an infimum? If so, does the property *every bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has an infimum* hold in ZF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completeness of $\Bbb R$ holds in $\sf ZF$, the axiom of choice has absolutely nothing to do with it.

And it seems to me that $x_n$ is the infimum of a closed set, which is indeed the minimum.